# How to find duration of signal from spectral domain?

Tags: signal-analysis, time-domain

I have spectral domain and I have to find duration of this signal (in time domain). How I can find?[image]

Comment: Duration = $(1/F_s) *N = T_s N$.  Or in words, 1/clock multiplied by number of samples

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you convert a signal from time-domain to frequency-domain for a particular duration, you are basically integrating out over time therefore you cannot say precisely what the signal duration was in the N number of samples you used to calculate your Frequency response. You can possibly use STFT for this purpose.